# In SQL, best way to loop children to get sales at each level?

Tags: sql-server

I wish to have all sales for an items, at each level of the production... and I'm not sure how to do this efficiency.

I have a table containing sales per SKU (pre-calulated each night).

It's like this :

```
SKU  -- SALES
--------------
SKU1 -- 123.34
SKU2 -- 452.23
SKU3 -- 183.12
...
```

And in the system, I have all the "PARENT" needed to make the SKU (if any)

Like this :

```
SKU  -- PARENT
---------------
SKU1 -- NULL
SKU2 -- SKU3
SKU3 -- SKU1
SKU4 -- NULL
SKU5 -- SKU1
...
```

As you can see, SKU1 is "root" and it's needed to make SKU3 and SKU5. To make SKU3, you will need SKU2 (So to make SKU2, you will need SKU1 => SKU3 => SKU2).

I first made a view to load all the SKU and then all the SKU -- PARENT.

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ITEMNO)) AS ITEMNO, '' AS PARENT1
FROM dbo.ICITEM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM dbo.ICITEMO T2
                  WHERE T2.OPTFIELD = 'PARENT1' AND T1.ITEMNO = T2.ITEMNO)

UNION ALL

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ITEMNO)) AS ITEMNO, LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(VALUE, '-', ''))) AS PARENT1
FROM dbo.ICITEMO T2
WHERE T2.OPTFIELD = 'PARENT1'
```

Then, made another view to get the children of each items (if any).

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ITEMNO)) AS ITEMNO, '' AS ENFANT1
FROM dbo.ICITEM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM dbo.VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1 T2
                  INNER JOIN dbo.VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1 AS VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1_1 ON T2.ITEMNO = VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1_1.PARENT1
                  WHERE T1.ITEMNO = T2.ITEMNO)

UNION ALL

SELECT dbo.VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1.ITEMNO, VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1_1.ITEMNO AS ENFANT1
 FROM dbo.VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1 
 INNER JOIN dbo.VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1 AS VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1_1 ON dbo.VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1.ITEMNO = VIEW_ICITEM_PARENT1_1.PARENT1
```

Then, I tried to run a code (took somewhere here) to run all the loop and get each level... if it was okay, I would add the sales calculations... but it took 2 hours to run and had some weird stuff in it.

```
with descendants as
( select ITEMNO, ENFANT1 as descendant, 1 as level
     from VIEW_ICITEM_ENFANT1
   union all
     select d.ITEMNO, s.ENFANT1, d.level + 1
    from descendants as d
       join VIEW_ICITEM_ENFANT1 s
        on d.descendant = s.ITEMNO
)
select *
from descendants
--order by ITEMNO, level, descendant

option (maxrecursion 5)
```

To explain a little more :

If I have this :

```
ROOT -- CHILD
A    -- B
A    -- C
B    -- D
B    -- E
C    -- NULL
```

I'm expecting this :

```
SKU -- SALES_DIRECT -- SALES_TOTAL
A   -- A            -- A+B+C+D+E
B   -- B            -- B+D+E
C   -- C            -- C
```

**Note**: Could also be a stored procedure if it's easier.

Comment: I don't completely follow your `SALES_TOTAL` column.  Why does `B` appear before `C`, given that both are direct children of `A`?

Comment: Cause to make  `B`, you need `A`, then in the "sales" (maybe I should call it "usage" instant of SALES). In other word, if you have sold `5 x B`, you will need `5 x A` to make `5 x B`. Then if A have been sold 2 times, you will have a total of `7 x A` sold.

Hope it's clear like this ?

Comment: Throw away your views, use a recursive CTE on the source table, and make sure the `SKU -- Parent` table is indexed on both columns.

Comment: @TabAlleman Maybe I don't see it clearly, but In the table, I'm only getting the parents and I need to work it the other way around (using childs). Or maybe I could just make a table and use that table to run the CTE, but it will be faster if I got a table instant of a view ?

Comment: Maybe to add a little more info that might help figure what is going on. We are talking about wood floor. So I'm starting with the "raw" plank **A** who will give either **B** (a raw, textured plank) that will give **D** (a finished, textured, varnished plank) or, will directly give **C** (a finished, varnished, untextured plank).

Comment: Please update your tags with the version of SQL Server that you're using.

Comment: Your second example (after "To explain a little more") is contradicting your first, and is probably a result of your overcomplicating the issue.  What does your actual raw table look like?

Comment: @TabAlleman 

I did what you said... I moved all the SKU and SKU_CHILDS into a Table and it's working very fast ! 

`with childrens as
( select SKU, SKU_ENFANT1 as children, 1 as level
     from dbo.ICITEM_ENFANT1
   union all
     select d.SKU, s.SKU_ENFANT1, d.level + 1
    from childrens as d
       join dbo.ICITEM_ENFANT1 s
        on d.children= s.SKU
)
select *
from childrens`

Comment: Hi, i think you can take look at this post : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/hierarchical-cumulative-sum-using-sql-server

Comment: @pascalsanchez thanks you sir, it's what I needed for my final solution! :)

Comment: @nka glad to help you :).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final request, running in 2 seconds with 33482 lines.

```
    ;with C as
    (
      select T.ID,
             T.SKU,
             (SELECT QTYSHIPPED FROM dbo.PRDATA_OEINV_TOTALQTYSHIPPED WHERE T.SKU = ITEMNO) as QtyShipped,
             T.SKU as RootID
      from ICITEM_ENFANT1 T
      union all
      select T.ID,
             T.SKU,
             (SELECT QTYSHIPPED FROM dbo.PRDATA_OEINV_TOTALQTYSHIPPED WHERE T.SKU = ITEMNO) as QtyShipped,
             C.RootID
      from ICITEM_ENFANT1 T
        inner join C
          on T.SKU_ENFANT1 = C.SKU
    )

    select T.ID,
           T.SKU,
           T.SKU_ENFANT1,
           (SELECT QTYSHIPPED FROM dbo.PRDATA_OEINV_TOTALQTYSHIPPED WHERE T.SKU = ITEMNO) as QtyShipped,
           S.AmountIncludingChildren
    from ICITEM_ENFANT1 T
      inner join (
                 select RootID,
                        sum(QtyShipped) as AmountIncludingChildren
                 from C
                 group by RootID
                 ) as S
        on T.SKU = S.RootID
    order by T.SKU,T.SKU_ENFANT1, QtyShipped
    option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Thanks for the help!